# Is it possible to set the default region in the BigQuery web console?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to set the BigQuery default region for uploads and queries in the web console? Currently, when I go to create table, it defaults to the US region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region location of the BigQuery product is dataset-based. That means that all the tables in the same dataset will be in the same region.

When you create a new dataset via the console, you are prompted choose one of the [following regions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#regional_locations), but you cannot change the dataset location later.

However, if it's essential to have the dataset in another region, you can [follow this steps](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#moving-data) to transfer the data to a new dataset in another location.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have the 'Default' value changed in the dataset creation process?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible to change the default region to be any other than 'US'. May I ask what method are you using to create the datasets? For example you can ad the `--location` flag in the `bq mk --dataset --default_table_expiration [EXPIRATION_TIME] --location EU[PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET_NAME]` command from the Cloud Shell.